# iOS crash on device with ARC enabled

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I've hit a problem that has me completely stumped. I'll illustrate with a code sample:

```
@interface Crasher ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *array;
@end

@implementation Crasher

- (void)crash;
{
  NSMutableArray *mutable = [NSMutableArray array];
  NSArray *items = @[@0, @1, @2, @3];

  if ([@YES boolValue])
  {
    [items enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
      [mutable addObject:obj];
    }];
  }
  else
  {
    [items enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
      [mutable addObject:obj];
    }];
  }

  [self setArray:mutable];
}

@end
```

The above code crashes on the `[self setArray:mutable]` line when ARC is enabled and it is run on a device. The code never crashes on the simulator nor does it crash on a device with ARC disabled. Using `NSZombieEnabled` indicates that the setter is attempting to retain an already-deallocated array.

It does not crash if the second `[mutable addObject:obj]` call is commented out (but this code is never executed in the first place).

I've uploaded a project that demonstrates this crash to Github to [`aidansteele/arc-crash`](https://github.com/aidansteele/arc-crash). I am using Xcode 4.5.2. It seems to not occur on Xcode 4.6, but that is still in developer preview. What am I doing wrong?

---

Addressing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13943891/216724) answer (in the question so that I have a bit more space), I don't believe the problem lies within `-[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:]` as the problem persists if I change that method call to use the following `-[NSArray(Functional) each:]` call.

```
@interface NSArray (Functional)
- (void)each:(void (^)(id obj))action;
@end

@implementation NSArray (Functional)

- (void)each:(void (^)(id))action;
{
  for (NSUInteger idx = 0; idx < [self count]; idx++)
  {
    action([self objectAtIndex:idx]);
  }
}

@end
```

Comment: on which line does the crash happen?

Comment: It's probably a problem with the block. What happens if you use ARC, but do the enumeration on the foreground thread instead of on a background thread? You probably don't want to call setArray until after the enumeration is done. Right now it is happening almost immediately. I'll bet if you made the items array big enough it would crash in the simulator.

Comment: @sergio I've edited the question to clarify that it happens when setting the property.

Comment: @MarkThalman I'm not sure I know what background thread you're talking about...

Comment: @MarkThalman If you have a look at the sample project, you will see that the application does nothing beyond execute this method upon application startup. It is executed on the main thread. In any case, the enumeration is executed synchronously.

Comment: If you're seeing a difference in your code's behavior from Xcode 4.5.2 to 4.6, then you're likely to be looking at an Xcode bug.  Please file it.

Comment: What happens if you do `NSMutableArray *mutable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` instead of the autoreleased version?

Comment: Probably works, but that's not the point, it should work with `array` too.

Comment: Yes, just tested myself, works.

Comment: Also works fine with `NSMutableArray *mutable = [@[] mutableCopy];` or any other method that traditionally increased the retain count.

Comment: I can only get this to crash in a release (optimized) build.  So my guess is a bug in the clang optimizer.  Further investigation required.

Answer (score 3):

Because this problem only occurs on the device (ARM code), and in a Release build (optimised code) I very much suspect you have found a bug in the Clang compiler's optimiser with respect to ARC and blocks and autorelease.  Raise a bug in Radar with your sample project as an attachment.

If you replace the enumerateObjectsUsingBlock with

```
for (id n in items)
{
   [mutable addObject:n];
}
```

you're crash will go away.

Other changes to the code that fix the problem:

Replace:

```
[NSMutableArray array];
```

with

```
[NSMutableArray new];
```

or

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Also, as an aside, you shouldn't be storing an NSMutableArray in a NSArray property.  You should be converting the NSMutableArray to an NSArray before assigning it to the property.  Eg:

```
self.array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutable];
```

Note that this won't fix the crash.  It is just better code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree that this is a really good candidate for submitting a radar, especially since he already has a sample project.

Comment: `[NSArray arrayWithArray:mutable]` sounds like a very round-about way of saying `[mutable copy]`. Even better, the `array` property should be declared with `copy` semantics.

Comment: Also, it's submitted as radar [#12905972](http://openradar.appspot.com/12905972) if anyone wishes to follow its progress.

Comment: If it's not occurring in Xcode 4.6, I wonder how much traction this radar will actually get. Apple is unlikely to go back and make changes to Xcode 4.5 at this point.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why you feel `[NSMutableArray new];` or `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` is better than `[NSMutableArray array];`?  Is this a personal preference, or is there a documented advantage?

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer may lie with the variable being auto-released, and the block making use of this auto-released variable.

From the Clang docs on [storage duration of __autoreleasing objects](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#storage-duration-of-autoreleasing-objects):

> A program is ill-formed if it declares an __autoreleasing object of
>   non-automatic storage duration. A program is ill-formed if it captures
>   an __autoreleasing object in a block or, unless by reference, in a
>   C++11 lambda.

So how to test if this is the issue?

First we see if the block capturing the mutable array really is the source of the issue.  Comment out the use of the mutable array in the first block (the only block called) and use NSLog on the value found by enumeration instead:

```
[items enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        //[mutable addObject:obj];
        NSLog(@"item is %@",obj);
    }];
```

That fixes the crash.  What if we simply reference the mutable array in a way that does not cause mutation (to make sure that mutation is not an issue)?

```
[items enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        //[mutable addObject:obj];
        NSLog(@"Mutable array is %@",mutable);
    }];
```

That still crashes, so we can tell just referencing the autoreleased mutable array in the block is causing an issue.  On a side note, you also get a crash using arrayWithCapacity correctly sized to hold all the values.

So how can we fix this issue, if the problem is a block capturing an autoreleased object?

We can make the variable strong instead, so that ARC has to release it:

```
   NSMutableArray *mutable = [NSMutableArray array];
```

That fixes the crash, and ARC properly releases the variable when the method is left.

However I am not wholly sure that is the full story - merely introducing this simple block anywhere in that method also fixes the crash:

```
  void (^useMute)();

    useMute = ^() {
        NSLog(@"Mutable is %@", mutable);
    };
```

Even if it is never used, it's causing the mutable array to be retained and preventing an early release also.  So it seems like the true error is somewhere with the interaction of enumerateUsingBlock and the auto-release pool.

On more of a side note, what also fixes the issue is to use normal enumeration instead of block enumeration:

```
   for (id obj in items )
      {
          [mutable addObject:obj];
      }
```

Sometimes it's better to use the simpler mechanisms to do things unless you have a great reason for using the fancier methods.  For a loop over array elements that is intended to be straight-forward synchronous code execution, why use a block if you don't need access to the other parameters the block passes you?  You even have more control using the C constructs continue and stop than the block loop, which only allows for stopping the enumeration entirely.

Comment: I should note that I was only using `-[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:]` for illustrative purposes. This problem is occurring in a much larger project, but I reduced it here to the minimal example that reproduces the issue. My apologies for not making this clear in the question and leading you on a wild goose chase!

Comment: It's also worth noting that commenting out usage of `mutable` in the _second_ block (i.e. the one that is never called) also causes this crash to go away.

Comment: I figured it was a problem in a larger project, but it seemed like the advice on a fix could be taken back to help whatever the real problem was... very interesting that commenting out the code not called causes any kind of issue.  Definitely file a radar.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an issue in the  `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` method for your version of SDK. Maybe you should read the release notes of the new SDK or known issues of the old one to find out more. So, what happens is, your retain count is just fine up to the point when you call `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock`. After that method exits, your pointer points to some garbage.

One way to fix it would be to take responsibility for your collection and promise you will not dispose of it before `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` exits. Although a fix, it doesn't tackle the core problem, which as I said above, I think it resides in `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock`. Here is a code that works(around).

```
#import "Crasher.h"

@interface Crasher ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *array;
@end

@implementation Crasher

- (void)crash;
{
  __block NSMutableArray *mutable = [NSMutableArray array];
  NSArray *items = @[@0, @1, @2, @3];

  if ([@YES boolValue])
  {
    [items enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
      [mutable addObject:obj];
    }];
  }
  else
  {
    [items enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
      [mutable addObject:obj];
    }];
  }

    NSLog(@"%@", mutable);

  [self setArray:mutable];
}

@end
```

Comment: I responded to your answer in the question body. This comment space doesn't really provide enough room for a nicely-formatted answer. :)

Comment: I see, then it must have something to do with blocks in general. try to create a new project, from a template, without modifing any settings and see if the same code causes the same problems.

Comment: one thing is sure, as soon as you use a block in your code, the retain count breaks. The workaround I propose still stands, but since it appears to be bigger than expected, you should find the root problem.

Comment: The sample project mentioned in the question body is indeed a fresh project that has nothing but this code added. It still has the same issue, unfortunately.